# Where can I find the question templates in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

After setting up my Team, there was a wizard at the top of the page, which among other things suggested posting a few questions and provided some templates for common questions.  I made the mistake of clicking `skip for now` to see if there was anything urgent I needed to do, but now I can't find the templates again.

Where can I go to find these question templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there's no way to get that back once you've dismissed it. We're currently working on a new onboarding experience that will allow resetting of onboarding coming in early next year.

I've included a screenshot of the suggestions we make. Clicking "Review & Post" simply prefilled the question title and the tag.

[image]

Comment: In that case, the *"for now"* is kinda misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  In the meantime, could the text of those templates be posted somewhere and/or sent to me?

Comment: @ScottWeldon I've updated my post with a screenshot of the onboarding suggestions.